# Personal Productivity is now in public beta - look out for new questions?

Tags: discussion, migration

[Personal Productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/) is now in public beta.

Therefore, if you see a question that might be on topic over there but definitely off topic here flag it for moderator attention and we'll take a look.

This doesn't apply to questions that could be on topic on either site (admittedly a small number) as there's always a chance that the site won't leave beta. However, if the question is *definitely* off topic and would otherwise be closed (and eventually deleted) then migrating it an option.

NOTE: Personally I'm not in favour of migrating old questions to a new site. However, new questions are always fair game.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a good idea.

It looks like they're still [defining what their FAQ is going to look like](https://productivity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38/help-design-our-first-draft-faq). It might be something we want to hold off on until they have a working FAQ so we mitigate any potential problems with their definition process.